# CHKDSK /R turns Perfect HDD Seagate 3TB to 0.7TB (marks the rest has bad)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, chkdsk, bad-sectors

Before I explain the problem, let me tell you what's not the problem. I don't have problems formatting or seeing the drive has 3TB, so please avoid this issue.

So, now the problem. I had this drive without any issues whatsoever, but i've decided to run `CHKDSK /R`, unfortunately, so after that it marks 2GB of the drive as bad sectors. Luckily I had that as free space.

So, I'd create the partition again with GPT, no problems. Get back to Windows, try `chkdsk` again, and bammm, there it goes back to only 0.7TB usable drive. So, I thought I had faulty drive, asked Seagate, and they sent me a "new" drive.

As I got the new, i've done the same test, with the same result, damn

I've decided to do another test, new partition, and try to fill the drive with movies, so I could see the thumbnail in windows explorer for a quick view if the data was ok. I've created a batch to copy 1 movie over and over until the drive was full.

After 1 day of copies, I get back and see immediately that some files had no preview thumbnail, and when opened didn't play. How come a simple copy of a working file not be ok?

After that, I tried `chkdsk /F` this time, and it found tons of errors in the tables; why is that? All the drive did was copy files, no more use to it.

It deleted data and remained with 2TB of data on drive, but curiously, it left some bad copies on it that didn't play at all.

At this point my head is scrambled and I don't know what to think of this drive. Is it ok? Is `chkdsk` the only problem and it destroys the drive? Why is this incompatibility happening?

I've decided to redo the copy of movie process again and fill the drive again, which is a very long process to fill 3TB. So far I'm at 1.4TB of data, and so far all files have a working thumbnail on windows explorer.

So, can anyone share some enlightenment?

**info:**

- Windows 7 64 bits
- Board Asus P5Q
- Chipset with latest drivers
- HDD Seagate ST3000DM001

**edit:**

Yesterday the 2nd process of filling the drive with a movie copy, at about 1.8TB of copied data i've decided to take a look, and already there were tons of corrupt video files, which is very stressing, why was this happening.

So i've canceled the process, and tried to install one of the tons of files i was testing from intel, so far all without success, but one "iata_enu.exe" which is Intel RST, did finally changed the version in my sata controller from 2008 to 2012, finally i had some hope, in case this was the problem. which is still strange, because if you go to Intel or Asus site to get the latest driver, you get the 2008 version.

So, 1 change made, but i've decided to do another. What if the problem from the corrupt files just on a COPY process were the copier itself? So i've dropped teracopy and changed the batch to use old dos copy command.

After these 2 changes, i've restarted my process of filling the drive with copies of a movie, so i can test the drive when it's full with chkdsk. So far, it copied 2.1TB and ALL files are working fine, don't know if this change comes from the driver or the copier. Let's wait 'till the end to then see if chkdsk changes behavior to.

Comment: Can you try it on a Linux live-cd to rule out any hardware issues?

Comment: Check the system logs for IO errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

The solution was that i had to guess that in order to get the latest driver of the sata controller, you shouldn't install the latest chipset drivers, or look for the latest sata controller on asus/intel site, noooooooo, you install Intel RST and it then installs you by courtesy a new driver, changing from one of 2008, that even windows update said "you're fine, this is the latest driver", to a new one of 2012.

go figure...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run a S.M.A.R.T check on that disk.
Since SMART runs from the disk itself it should be agnostic to driver and chipset issues.